# How to combine both characters and number in an unsigned array char

Tags: c

I want to see if this is actually possible in C code.

```
unsigned char message[] = {0x00,0x00,"Hello world"};
```

---

There is some firmware that I want to force to take characters other than 0x00 in the same array.  It has:

```
unsigned char message[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

already written in it. I want it to take other characters since both these are possible:

```
unsigned char message[] = "Hello world";

unsigned char message2[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00};
```

I have a buffer that stores letters from a UART which I want to combine with

```
 unsigned char message2[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00};
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have many messages like that?

Comment: and why do you think that "Hello World" is a character or integer?

Comment: u`nsigned char message[] = "\0\0Hello world";`  Printing it is another story,

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler told you, you can't do what you attempted in the way you attempted to do it.

Note that you could use:

```
unsigned char message[] = "\x00\x00Hello world";
```

but considerable care is required since:

```
unsigned char message[] = "\x00\x00Byebye world";
```

has a second byte containing `\xB` or `\013` and the third byte is `y`. The hex escape stops at the first character that is not a hexadecimal digit (so `"\x00Babaganoush"` has six digits in the hex escape; and there are lots of ways of spelling 'Babaganoush').